# Adding a tapRecognizer to a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to add a tapRecognizer to detect single taps on a UIScrollView so that it wont interfere with the paging and scrolling?

If so, hows is this set up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it works, you have to do something like this :

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[self addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[tap release];
```